# MySQL query ignoring NOT argurment

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run that filters certain data from the result, including making sure that none of the records that have 'A_null_choice' as a value for it's moduleName.

```
$sql = "SELECT am.moduleID, m.moduleName, am.type, s.regNum, s.award
FROM tbl_awardModules am
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_module m ON am.moduleID = m.moduleID
INNER JOIN tbl_awardLevels al ON am.awardLevelID = al.awardLevelID
INNER JOIN tbl_award a ON al.awardID = a.awardID
INNER JOIN tbl_student s ON a.awardID = s.award
WHERE am.type <> 'C' AND regNum = '$student_id' AND m.moduleName NOT LIKE 'A_null_Choice'";
```

The rest of the query runs fine and there are no errors etc, it just keeps showing the records with that value.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Is `'A_null_choice'` the actual value or is it actually `null`?

Comment: I'm assuming it has to do with this complex set of joins you are doing?

Comment: panic over and thanks for all your help, it turned out that for some stupid reason my browser wasn't refreshing the page so no matter what I did the content on the screen remained the same. System rebooted and script behaves at it should